# How to disable deep links in my UIWebView

Tags: uiwebview, ios9, deep-linking, deeplink

I've developed a web browsing app based on a UIWebView. All good until iOS 9 and the new way it handles universal links. For some reasons, when the user touch a link, I want him to stay in my browser instead of switching to the associated app (Twitter, Linkedin, Facebook, etc.). Is there a way to do that?